# Throttling with Concurrent Consumers

Tags: apache-camel

According to Camel's documentation on the [Throttler EIP](http://camel.apache.org/throttler.html), a route like the following would allow no more than 10 messages to hit the queue:b endpoint in any given 1000 millisecond period:

```
from("queue:a").throttle(10).to("queue:b");
```

I am having trouble finding documentation that explains whether or not throttling is done on a per-thread basis or a per route basis. Given the following route, will each consumer be allowed to send no more than 10 messages to queue:b, or will the entirety of all consumers be restricted to 10 messages per unit time?

```
from("queue:a?concurrentConsumers=20")
    .to("bean:myBean?method=doSomeExpensiveLongRunningCalculations)
    .throttle(10).asyncDelayed()
    .to("bean:myBean?method=makeAPICallToExternalService")
    .to("bean:myBean?method=performMoreCalculationsAndSave");
```

The reason I must throttle above is due to a rate limit imposed by a third-party API.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its global, so its 10 per second no matter which consumer threads are used to send the message to the throttler.

Comment: Awesome! I was hoping that was the case!

Comment: Hi when I am having three consumer and throttling rate specified is 10. Then it is throttling at 10X3=30 per second. Ideally it should be 10 message per second. Am right Claus?